# Is there a way to read a c-string and then an int with a single scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

Hey,
I'm trying to get this function to get the following output with the listed input, the "..." is where I'm not sure what to write:

```
void Question8(void)
{
  char sentence[100];    
  int grade;    
  scanf(….);    
  printf("%s %d", sentence, grade);    
}

Input:
My CS Grade is 1000

Output:
My CS Grade is 100
```

However, the kicker is that I need the scanf to read a c-string and then an int with a single scanf command, is this even possible?

**Edit:
I can only edit the code in the location with the three periods ( "..." ), I cannot use anything more.  I can assume that the input listed is expected but I cannot change anything outside of the three periods.
The output does not contain typos, the purpose of this assignment is to use flags and escape sequences.**

Comment: Please post, _verbatim_ the assignment at the bottom of your answer. This keeps changing and we keep answering. First you couldn't assume what the string would be, then you could .. it's better if we understand what the _teacher_ wants when helping with homework.

Comment: Is there a typo in your input/output or is the user supposed to type in a grade of 1000 (one thousand) and receive a grade of 100 (one hundred) as output?

Comment: Do not know if negative credit needs to be accounted for, the accepted answer will not work with negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in **Visual Studio 2008**

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      char sentence[100];    
      int grade = 0;    
      scanf("%[^0-9] %d",sentence,&grade);
      printf("%s %d", sentence, grade);   
      return 1;
    }


Input : 
My CS Grade is 100
Output :
My CS Grade is 100
```

Comment: @Aux: This doesn't work, it outputs two spaces between `is` and `1000` and also outputs `1000`, not `100`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll get this over with quick:

```
<obligatory_rant>
    stupid question, but I guess it's homework and you're
    stuck with these absurd limitations
</obligatory_rant>
```

Then, if you need to read everything up to but excluding the first digit, then the number:

```
if (scanf("%100[^0-9] %3d", text, &number) == 2)
    ...
```

Notes:

- `100` in `"%100[...` should be whatever your actual buffer size is to protect against buffer overrun.
- The `%3d` documents that at most 3 digits should partake the the numeric value, so 1000 is correctly read as 100.
- `[^...]` means the string made up of characters not ("^") in the following set, which is then specified as `0-9` - the digits.
- `if (... == 2)` tests whether both positional parameters were scanned /  converted successfully.

If you can't add an `if` and error message, then simply:

```
scanf("%100[^0-9] %3d", text, &number)
```

Comment: I cannot use anything other than the exact lines of code in the question.  I have to gain the necessary output with a single scanf.

Comment: @Aux - The `scanf()` part is what you need. The surrounding `if(...)` statement is a safety check - `scanf` returns the number of arguments it successfully assigned data to (in this case 2 if the user entered data in the correct format) and the `if` statement just verifies that this happened. It isn't needed if your teacher wants you to write bad code. :P

Comment: How can that be?  The code in your question uses "%s %d".  `%s` stops scanning at the first space.  It *can not* work for your input.  My code above has a single `scanf` - just with different format and arguments.

Comment: @Chris: good point - it might be the `if` that's confusing Aux... thanks.

Comment: @Chris - I give up on this one, glad to see it got your attention :)

Comment: @Tony - You need to do `"%.*[^0-9]"`. Your current format seems to be trying to mix `"%["` and `"%s"` somehow, but I'm sure it was just a neural segfault on your part, though.

Comment: @Chris: so I do... must be going blind to have missed that.

Comment: With `scanf()`, the `*` means 'suppress the assignment', which is not what you want.  You can't do variable lengths in the format string; you have to write the string with the actual length in place: `"%.30[^0-9] %d"`.  Yes, `scanf()` is weird.

Comment: @Jonathan - I was just checking up on that and came to the same conclusion. Can we all collectively agree that `scanf` is poorly designed and that we should stop using it?

Comment: @Chris: fine by me - I stopped using it for anything complex years ago.  It's a bit tough on people whose teachers think that knowing `scanf()` is important, though. (The important lesson is "`scanf()` is usually not the answer - now, what was the question?") The code that has to be filled in is also a disaster because it does not check whether `scanf()` succeeded in parsing 2 fields or not.

Comment: @Jonathan: right you are, thanks!... (well, just "%30..." rather than "%.30...") - will fix... been doing C++ too long and don't use this often - got confused with printf() formats :-/.

Comment: Yup - I wondered about the '.' and couldn't remember and didn't fix it while the comment was still editable.  I don't use `scanf()` because it is too hard to use it correctly.  I pity the kids made to use it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to read pre-formatted string using scanf, however the format must be strict.
This version will continue to read the input until a digit is encountered and then read an integer. 
Here is your code again:

```
  char sentence[100];
  int grade;
  scanf("%[^0-9] %d",sentence,&grade);
  printf("%s %d\n", sentence, grade);
```

Comment: That's the exact same thing I had at first and it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? I tried this with my GCC compiler and it seems to work.

Comment: I much prefer @Tony's version with bounds checking if he had gotten it right. +1 for making me do a double-check of the syntax for `"%["`.

Comment: @Aux: This doesn't work, it outputs two spaces between `is` and `1000` and also outputs `1000`, not `100`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really horrible question. A correct set of scanf parameters would be `"%14c%3d", sentence, &grade`

Because a space is included in the `printf` statement the trailing space needs to not be stored in sentence. Because the input contains other spaces there is no other solution (that I can thing of) than a fixed length. The integer parsing also requires a fixed length to truncate `1000` to `100`.

I can think of no reason to ever write code anything like this. The code fits the requirements but wouldn't be useful in any other circumstances. I think that this is a very poor training exercise.